# Can anyone shed some light on why there is a big performance hit here?

Tags: php, performance, debugging

1 or 2 seconds

```
$url = trim($_POST['url']);
$html = @file_get_contents($url);
```

30+ seconds to load

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$html = @file_get_contents(trim($url));
```

I'm always curious when I discover things like this what is going on under the hood.

Cheers,

Comment: Are you sure `$url` wasn't just slow to load that particular time? How many times did you try this out?

Comment: What URL string are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure but is it due to the function composition? Or maybe the url's response is slow. Note that the speed of a page load doesn't only depend on PHP, it also depends on the server speed, the user's speed, and the internet connection speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't be expecting that much of a performance increase for `trim` in fact, I've never seen anything that would even suggest why that would be happening.

What are you using to post your data with? Sure it's not a fluke?